# How to completely unload the readline module in python?

Tags: python, readline, ncurses, python-curses

I want to dynamically disable the readline functionality by completely getting rid of it. Not by disabling tab completion or any other provided functionality, but to completely unhook it, free resources.

I have a program that uses ncurses for display purposes, but returns to the normal terminal where you can type stuff into Python's input() function field. Everything works except for terminal resizing and updating the LINES and COLS variables inside curses. We are presented with this dreaded error upon resizing:

```
    c = stdscr.get_wch()
_curses.error: no input
```

Minimal program to reproduce:

```py
import readline
import curses

def c_main(stdscr):
    while True:
        c = stdscr.get_wch()
        stdscr.insstr(0, 0, repr(c))

curses.wrapper(c_main)
```

I tried removing the module from `sys.modules`, getting rid of the name `del readline`, garbage collecting, but it is all futile.

```
print(readline.__file__)
```

gives: `/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

I think I understand that I have to obtain the handle for this file and somehow unload it with ctypes, but I have no idea how to do it. Alternatively, could someone point me in the right direction on how to reconcile these two libraries to make resizing work? Thank you.

Comment: Add a signal handler for SIGWINCH.

Comment: If you want to use Python interactively from a script, you could use the [code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html) module.