# Why does the readline module cause curses screen size not to get updated?

Tags: python, readline, curses

This simple app serves as a minimal example:

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    while True:
        stdscr.clear()
        window_size = stdscr.getmaxyx()
        stdscr.addstr(1, 1, str(window_size))
        stdscr.refresh()
        if stdscr.getch() == 17:  # Ctrl + Q
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

The app prints the current window size on the screen. I expect that if I resize the window while the program is running, the numbers will change. And it does exactly that.

The problem is I'm using `curses` in a larger application that also needs the module `readline` (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2533142/7585848)). And I found out that if `readline` is imported (doesn't even have to be used), the above program no longer works: the numbers still show up, but they do not get updated when the screen size changes.

It took me hours to track down this bug, as I would never have expected that merely importing a module -- without using it -- could change the program's behavior.

Theoretically, what is causing this behavior? And practically, how can I resolve this conflict? I have tried only importing `readline` inside functions that need it, but that doesn't work either: once a function that imports `readline` is called, the `curses` app stops working.

As I'm writing this question, I find out someone already asked [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71819170/how-to-completely-unload-the-readline-module-in-python). The question had no answers, so I hope it's fair to ask it again.

Comment: This answers your question: [KEY_RESIZE not returned from getch() when xterm is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520435/key-resize-not-returned-from-getch-when-xterm-is-resized/54525594#54525594)